# What's the scope of a variable defined inside a loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scope

According to the JavaScript documentation, variables created within a function are local to that function. However, I found that not using the literal `var` when the variable is declared inside a for-loop causes unexpected behaviour (e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/carlesaraguz/ao77ac2L/)

Why is that?

```js
function iterate1() {
    var array = ["hello", "world"];
    var str = "";
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        str += "iterate0 --- " + i + ": " + array[i] + "<br>";
        iterate2(array);
        str += "iterate0 --- " + i + ": " + array[i] + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("output0").innerHTML = str;
}

function iterate2(arr) {
    var str = ""
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        str += "iterate1 --- " + i + ": " + arr[i] + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = str;
}

$(function() {
    iterate1();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="output0"></p>
<p id="output1"></p>
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code her at SO

Comment: I didn't want to post code here because the JSFiddle was written as a mere complementary example. I guess the question is clearer with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not using "var" before declaring a variable, you are creating a global variable instead of a local one.

```js
function f1() {
  for (var i = 0; i...) {
    // i is local to this function 
  }
}

function f2() {
  for (i = 0; i...) {
    // i is a global variable
  }
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470494/5780021 for more info about this

Comment: This is a general information; it did not answer the context of the question by explaining what exactly happen in this case to get such output. So it’s not a complete answer for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what happens when you forget to put var.
The scope of your variable becomes global

```
(function() {
    myVar = 1;
    console.log("myVar should be 1: " + myVar); // should be 1
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("myVar should be 1, but isn't: " + myVar); // should be 1, but isn't 
    }, 100);
})();

(function() {
    for(myVar = 1; myVar < 10; myVar++) {
        // nothing, just increment var
    }
})();
```

You'll notice that there are two functions isolated from each other, but are actually using the same `myVar`

To add, `var`'s scope is the function it's enclosed in after it's declaration, regardless if it's declared in a `for` loop or `if` or any other type of block level statement.

In your particular case, here's what's happening.

iterate0 - 0 - hello | declared `i` as `global` with value of 0, print
iterate1 - 0 - hello | change value of `i` to 0, print and then increment `i` after
iterate1 - 1- world | `i` is 1 from previous incrementation, print, increment again after the loop
iterate0 - 2 - undefined | `i` is 2 from previous incrementation, print, increment again bumping it up to `3`
end